# Fails to update ContentVersion with Java SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, java, wsdl, enterprise-wsdl

I am querying some records of type `ContentVersion`, changing `Title` then updating that records through

```java
ContentVersion contentVersionToUpdate = new ContentVersion();
contentVersionToUpdate.setTitle(newFileTitle);
contentVersionToUpdate.setId(contentVersion.getId());
```

Once I pass this instance to update through my connection through the following steps

```java
SaveResult[] saveResults = this.enterpriseConnection.update(new sObject[] { contentVersionToUpdate  });
```

I receive this error: `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY: You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. []`

I tried to find out what is the problem using Execute Anonymous. If I query the fields `Title` and `VersionData` and try to update it through DML it does give me the same error. If I remove `VersionData` from the query and execute the DML it simply works.

Even though according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) that field is updateable and I am doing all these operation with a "System Administrator" profile. I can't seem to understand why on the Java code it does not work even if I am not doing `contentVersionToUpdate.setVersionData(base64Data)`.